# Interpretation of a tightly paired learning curve with increasing loss

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost

I am assessing models for a binary classification task and have created a model with a very strange learning curve. This is the learning curve of an sklearn AdaBoostClassifier fitted with default parameters:

[image: Tuned AdaBoost learning curve]

I've also attempted other parameter combinations and still see essentially the same shape.

When using the f1-score as the learning curve metric, then the shape is more familiar:

[image: AdaBoost f1 learning curve]

For reference I've included the learning curve of a logistic regression model trained on the same dataset:

[image: logistic regression learning curve]

Comparing these two models from a performance standpoint, AdaBoost does much better with an f1-score of 0.72 while the logistic classifier has an f1-score of 0.66. However, the shape of the learning curve has left me uncertain as to whether I have a good model or not.

Is log loss inappropriate to use with AdaBoost for some reason?